# How to make a Content Slider like this structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image]

Is this structure reasonable to achieve?
By lining up li elements and hiding the content that exceed the parent div?
Sorry for my poor English, I hope my figure can make you understand what I' m trying to say...

Comment: Can you show your attempt, or at least a draft of the HTML structure?

Comment: Search for "CSS Carousel" or "image slider" in Google.

Comment: Sorry, I am trying to understand your question. Could you compare and contrast your model with this standard one : https://css-tricks.com/examples/FeaturedContentSlider/

Answer (score 0):

Hey I'm looking for fast, lightweight javascript slider.

**Owl-Carousel**

A lightweight Javascript plugin. I'm using this for my project now

http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/

**jQuery lightSlider**

I've never use this, but looks awesome with thumbnail.

http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/